# Orbeon Form Builder buid failed in Liferay configuration

Tags: ant, liferay, liferay-6, orbeon

Hi I am completely new to Orbeon and Liferay.

I have deployed orbeon.war into Liferay and I have created a form with Orbeon Form Builder. I am trying to create a build for the form but it fails in the WINDOWS Command prompt.I have download the 4.8 CE from www.orbeon.com.

Ant version:1.8.4

Tomcat7

I am run the following command after clean the ant cache

$ant clean

$ant proxy-portlet-war
and it showing following log

```
D:\Software's\Orbeon\orbeon-forms-tag-release-4.8-ce>ant proxy-portlet-war
Buildfile: D:\Software's\Orbeon\orbeon-forms-tag-release-4.8-ce\build.xml

init:
     [echo] Building Orbeon Forms 4.8.0.201503021129
     [echo] Using Ant Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.4 compiled on May 22 2012
     [echo] ##teamcity[buildNumber '4_8_0_201503021129']

set-version:
    [mkdir] Created dir: D:\Software's\Orbeon\orbeon-forms-tag-release-4.8-ce\build\src
     [copy] Copying 1 file to D:\Software's\Orbeon\orbeon-forms-tag-release-4.8-ce\build\src

prepare:
    [mkdir] Created dir: D:\Software's\Orbeon\orbeon-forms-tag-release-4.8-ce\build\classes
    [mkdir] Created dir: D:\Software's\Orbeon\orbeon-forms-tag-release-4.8-ce\build\lib

classpath:

classes:
   [scalac] Compiling 1 source file to D:\Software's\Orbeon\orbeon-forms-tag-release-4.8-ce\build\cl
asses
   [scalac] Compiling 0 scala and 538 java source files to D:\Software's\Orbeon\orbeon-forms-tag-rel
ease-4.8-ce\build\classes
   [scalac] Compiling 456 source files to D:\Software's\Orbeon\orbeon-forms-tag-release-4.8-ce\build
\classes
   [scalac] Compiling 1 source file to D:\Software's\Orbeon\orbeon-forms-tag-release-4.8-ce\build\cl
asses
   [scalac] warning: there were 21 deprecation warning(s); re-run with -deprecation for details
   [scalac] one warning found
    [javac] D:\Software's\Orbeon\orbeon-forms-tag-release-4.8-ce\build.xml:374: warning: 'includeant
runtime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] Compiling 538 source files to D:\Software's\Orbeon\orbeon-forms-tag-release-4.8-ce\build
\classes
    [javac] javac: invalid flag: D:\Software
    [javac] Usage: javac <options> <source files>
    [javac] use -help for a list of possible options

BUILD FAILED
D:\Software's\Orbeon\orbeon-forms-tag-release-4.8-ce\build.xml:374: Compile failed; see the compiler
 error output for details.

Total time: 1 minute 32 seconds
```

I am unable to configure the form in Liferay.

Answer (score 0):

Please include **includeantruntime="false"** in your **javac** task. See my example     `<javac destdir="${dest.dir}//classes" classpathref="project.classpath" debug="on" fork="true" includeantruntime="false" memoryinitialsize="256m" memorymaximumsize="1024m">`

Comment: no it is not working. Again same error it shown. I have increase the memory size and  I have added includeantruntime="false"  text in build.xml file.

Comment: We haven't tried building on Windows in a very long time. It seems that your error might be due to spaces in directory names. Why do you need to rebuild Orbeon Forms from source? You can of course, but that shouldn't be a necessary step to deploy a form.